# vb.net - showing 6 or more decimal places

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, double

Sample code here show below

```
lbUnit.Items.Add(String.Format("{0:n4}", dr1("unit_price")))
lbUnit1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0:n4}", dr1("unit_price")))
```

> note that : dr1("unit_price") this unit_price is get from msSQL Server

this 2 statement show 4 decimal places
eg.

showing like this `0.013`
but i want is `0.012543`

when change to `"{0:n4}"` to `"{0:n6}"` and `"{0:g}"` also get same result is that any solution else can make it show all the decimal places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `{0:0.000000}` or `{0:0.00####}` which will only show more places if nescessary.

Comment: This should work. Have you double checked that your DataTable realy contains `0.0123543`?

Comment: What is the result of `dr1.Table.Columns["unit_price"].DataType` ?

Comment: you mean the table datatype if yes, then it is decimal

Comment: Ok, since you are using VB.Net without casting you rely on implicit conversion ( dr("...") returns an object type ). You should try `DirectCast(dr1("unit_price"), GetType(decimal))`

Comment: I get this error `Compiler Error Message: BC30180: Keyword does not name a type`

Comment: Sorry, my fault `DirectCast(dr1("unit_price"), decimal)`, `GetType` is used in this context `Dim t as Type = GetType(decimal)` but not for `DirectCast`

Answer (score 0):

Use `N6` as the [numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

```
myDecimal.ToString("N6")
```

*Or:*

```
String.Format("{0:N6}", myDecimal)
```

*Or:*

```
Dim d As Double = 0.123
Dim sDisplayValue As String = d.ToString("0.000000")
```